# Automating failover to recovery site using SRM (API)

Tags: failover, vmware-srm

i am looking for a product that could integrate with SRM (we support following HW vendors: NetApp, EMC, Hitachi, Eternus and HP) and allow automation of failover from primary to disaster triggered by some sort of event on primary site.

Is there any such product

Thanks in advance,
B.

Answer (score 3):

Not to my knowledge.

I also don't think this is a desired behavior. If your SRM setup is complete -- protection groups created and recovery plans created, then triggering a failover is something that you really want to perform intentionally in a disaster or other critical scenario.